# Use password instead of ssh key for gitkraken or sourcetree

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, gitkraken

I'm using GitKraken (and Sourcetree) to manage git repositories, and it keeps asking me to configure ssh keys to pull code for a Pantheon repo. Pantheon doesn't use SSH keys for authentication, it uses passphrases for the repo, yet the git clients still expect an SSH key for a nonexistent task.

How do I configure these clients to default to a password for repos that only require passwords?

I tried to pull a repository with a password and it keeps asking me for a ssh key that doesn't exist.